# Cross-build scala API for various spark version

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

i know that it exist cross-build options to generate various version of a scala API running with different scala version. Let's say i will stay with the same scala version `2.11.12`, how can i set my `build.sbt` to handle multiple version of spark. I have some hint about the `"provided"` option for dependencies but i'm not sure it is the best way to handle it.

Bonus: what if some spark version are using 2.11 and others 2.12...

Please let us know if you've already ridden through this issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.2"
```

Use the double % -sign  when defining dependencies, sbt then will handle the scala version for you. You should use the same scala version for all your dependencies.